# Connect to DB with PHP Class isn't working when try to retrieve results

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning.

I'm trying to make a DB class to connect and retrieve results from my DB. So, I think with the class is everything good. But, the results won't appear.

Here is my DB class:

```
<?php class Conexao {

var $host    = "localhost";
var $usuario = "root";
var $senha = "xxxxxx";
var $banco = 'restaurante';
private $mysqli;

public function Abrir()
{
$this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->usuario, $this->senha, $this->banco);
}

public function Fechar()
{
$this->mysqli->close();
}
}

class Comando {
public function Executar($sql)
{
$con = new Conexao();
$con->Abrir(); 
$re = $con->mysqli->query($sql);
$con->Fechar();
return $re;
}
}
?>
```

And here is where I'm trying to retrieve the results:

```
<?php

$queryMesasAtivas = Comando::Executar('SELECT * FROM mesas WHERE status =1 AND numero !="'.$_SESSION["mesa"].'"');

if ($queryMesasAtivas->num_rows > 0) {  

while ($rowMesasAtivas = $queryMesasAtivas->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<option value='".$rowMesasAtivas['numero']."'>Mesa ".$rowMesasAtivas['numero']."</option>";
}
}
else {
echo '<option>Nenhuma mesa ativa</option>';
}

 ?>
```

I tried some modifications but, nothing changes. Everytime it's still not working. What's wrong?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: var?You ar mixing javascript syntax in php

Comment: @Mihai, `var` is perfectly valid syntax for PHP

Comment: @Mihai, please see example 1 on the [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: Your issue here is you are trying to use the `Executar` as a static member, youd have to initialise the class and use it with the `->` syntax, e.g. `$class = new Comando(); $class->Executar('SELECT * FROM mesas WHERE status =1 AND numero !="'.$_SESSION["mesa"].'"')`. If you want it static declare the `Executar` function as `public static function Executar`

Comment: What does "Everytime it's still not working" mean? Please provide actual output, expected output and maybe even a few relevant records from your DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `Comando::Executar` is not static, but rather declared as `public function...`, you will have to do something such as:

```
$comando = new Comando();

$queryMesasAtivas = $comando->Executar('SELECT * FROM mesas WHERE status =1 AND numero !="'.$_SESSION["mesa"].'"');

if ($queryMesasAtivas->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($rowMesasAtivas = $queryMesasAtivas->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value='".$rowMesasAtivas['numero']."'>Mesa ".$rowMesasAtivas['numero']."</option>";
    }
}
else {
    echo '<option>Nenhuma mesa ativa</option>';
}
```

Or declare the method as static, namely:

```
public static function Executar($sql)
{
    $con = new Conexao();
    $con->Abrir();
    $re = $con->mysqli->query($sql);
    $con->Fechar();
    return $re;
}
```

And then you can use the double colon (`::`) syntax:

```
$queryMesasAtivas = Comando::Executar('SELECT * FROM mesas WHERE status =1 AND numero !="'.$_SESSION["mesa"].'"');
```

I would suggest **not** calling an open and close every time you run a query, but rather a class like this:

```
class Conexao
{
    private $link;

    public function __construct($host = null, $username = null, $password = null, $dbName = null)
    {
        $this->link = mysqli_init();
        $this->link->real_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbName) or die("Failed to connect");
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->link->close();
    }

    public function Query($sql)
    {
        return $this->link->query($sql);
    }
}
```

This is then used as such:

```
$conexao = new Conexao("host", "username", "password", "db_name");
$result = $conexao->Query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` ASC;");
```

This is not only smaller, but more lightweight on the server because you aren't permanently opening and closing database connections, reducing CPU use and memory use.

Using static properties for the host etc. (keeps them in memory even after `__destruct` is used so you do not need to redeclare them every time):

```
class Conexao
{
    private $link;
    private static $host, $username, $password, $dbName;

    public function __construct($host = null, $username = null, $password = null, $dbName = null)
    {
        static::$host = $host ? $host : static::$host;
        static::$username = $username ? $username : static::$username;
        static::$password = $password ? $password : sattic::$password;
        static::$dbName = $dbName : $dbName : static::$dbName;
        $this->link = mysqli_init();
        $this->link->real_connect(static::$host, static::$username, static::$password, static::$dbName) or die("Failed to connect");
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->link->close();
    }

    public function Query($sql)
    {
        return $this->link->query($sql);
    }
}

$conexao = new Conexao("host", "username", "password", "db_name");
$result = $conexao->Query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` ASC;");

$conexao->__destruct(); // Destroy the class
$conexao = new Conexao(); // Reinitialise it
$result = $conexao->Query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` ASC;");
```

Using a config instance of the connection class:

config.php file:

```
<?php

require_once 'path/to/Conexao.php';
$conexao = new Conexao("host", "username", "password", "db_name");

?>
```

index.php file:

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';
$result = $conexao->Query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `id` ASC;");

?>
```

The class now has a parent on [my github](https://github.com/swiftie821/DBConnector)!

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, thanks for an example with smaller and lightweight. I'm using your example now. So, to result something, I need to do: $queryMesasAtivas = Query('SELECT * FROM mesas WHERE status =1 AND numero !="'.$_SESSION["mesa"].'"'); or need to make a new Conexao before? Edit: forget, now I see the use example, will try it.

Comment: Ok! Now it's working. Just a question: have some way to make the declarations of host, username, all of this inside class? So I don't need to set this in all pages?

Comment: @RodrigoBRF, edit added with `static` properties that keep the value

Comment: @RodrigoBRF, I have amended again because the `static`s were being updated every time, now they will hold value over pages :)

Comment: I think the best way would be to create a config file and use `require_once  'path/to/config.php';` where you'd need the instance every time however, rather than multi instance of the same class, I will add an edit to show this for you :)

Comment: Perfect Sam! Just another doubt. If I want to make an IF to check if the affected row is affected to make something. For example: $strSQL = $conexao->Query("INSERT INTO clientes(id_cliente,nome,checkout,metodo_pag,valor) VALUES (NULL, 'Nome Cliente', NOW(), '0', '$valorTotal')");

  if ($strSQL->affected_rows == 1) {

This returns Trying to get property of non-object in. How to make it work?

Comment: That's a cause for a new question, there are many dependencies with that for me to add it to this answer :)

Comment: @RodrigoBRF, if you add a new question, make sure to link to this Q&A for supporting documentation :)

Comment: Thanks! I've made a new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829118/if-affected-rows-returning-non-object-error-with-db-class