# If affected_rows returning non-object error with DB class

Tags: php, mysql

[My Question About DB Class for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825065/connect-to-db-with-php-class-isnt-working-when-try-to-retrieve-results/33825301?noredirect=1#comment55420288_33825301)

Hi! In this question above (link) I was with a problem with connection to DB with PHP CLASS. Now it's working. But, after the commands I've understood in this topic, I'm having a problem now with affected_rows.

```
$strSQL = $conexao->Query("INSERT INTO clientes(id_cliente,nome,checkout,metodo_pag,valor) VALUES (NULL, 'Nome Cliente', NOW(), '0', '$valorTotal')");

if ($strSQL->affected_rows == 1) {
```

When I execute it, the PHP returns "Trying to get property of non-object in".

What's wrong? Isn't the var $strSQL checking if $conexao->Query was done sucessful?

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Comment: `->affected_rows`is an object attribute, if `$conexao->Query()` is false, that means that `$strSQL`is not an object so you can not acces object properties

Comment: $strSQL doesn't "check" ANYTHING. it's simply where you're storing the return value from the query call. It's up to YOU to check what that return value is. Never EVER assume success on a db operation.

Comment: With the class I made for Rodrigo (only just thought of this), `$conexao->Query();` returns the result (`mysqli_result | bool`) meaning and the constrctor returns mysqli, meaning that you would have to add a function to get the affected rows, namely: `public function affected_rows() { return $this->link->affected_rows; }` and this *should* get the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use validation on the result from the query:

```
$rs = $conexao->Query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE 1;");
if ($rs)
    print $rs->affected_rows;
```

This allows you to be able to check if it has rows/isn't false etc and use the result and give your own error if not

Class that I am creating for MySQLi extension and use [found here](https://github.com/swiftie821/DBConnector)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much! And of course, I'll take a loot at your extension! I'm so glad that have some people that really want to help and not only judge. Everyone can have doubts and need help sometimes.

Comment: @RodrigoBRF, everyone has doubts, but we just need a helping hand and someone to teach us and in turn to teach to :P

Comment: Hey! @Sam Swift, I think you can give a little help here with a similar problem. I have a login system which I use "$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST['usuarioID']);". It's not working. I made a new topic about it in my another account. I'm trying to use this login with your DB class file that you created for me.

Comment: @RodrigoBRF, add another question with details and both me and the community can see what we can do :)

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the example from the [**manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) (as linked by Fred -ii-), the connection is used:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT CountryCode FROM Language");
printf("Affected rows (SELECT): %d\n", $mysqli->affected_rows); // Here
$result->close();
```

After looking at Sam Swift 웃's comment, I noticed my mistake... Here is one way to get what you want (mentioned in the comment)...

First, create a function on your class `Conexao`:

```
public function affected_rows(){
    return $this->link->affected_rows;
}
```

And then use it like this (after `$conexao->Query("INSERT [...]`):

```
if($conexao->affected_rows == 1) {
[...]
```

Also note the return from [mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Comment: `$conexao->affected_rows` wouldn't work as the class that I made does not derive from the mysqli class and therefore does not have its properties, to do this you would have to make the `private static $link` public and access it accordingly

Comment: @SamSwift웃 Yeah, MB ^^... Can I edit to match the suggestion on your comment on the question?

Comment: Don't have to ask me, SO is all about helping and developing. I have no problems with other developers taking my code and making it a million times better :P

Comment: Also just thought, you could add a `public static $last_result;` that is used to store the last result if it is `true/mysqli_result`on success, that will allow for getting the `affected_rows` and other properties :P

Comment: **#SoManyThingsToDoInAClass!** xD

Comment: That's an interesting thing to add ^^. But, maybe for future editions and re-uses, create an independent connection file and different `DAO`-s to separete things. TBH, it all depends on the OP's project and choice :D. Good practices + creativity might bring wonders. @SamSwift웃, can you tell me if the answer now corresponds to your comment?

Comment: I am also now in the process of making a mysqli extension class for a lot of the functionality and to give more :P

Comment: I do not, however I am tempted to add it to a public repo, if I do, I shall link it in my answer

Comment: Thinking about it, I'll do it now :)